# Aluminum alloy or carbon fibre handlebar?

Tags: handlebars, carbon, aluminum

Should I buy a carbon fibre handebar or an aluminium alloy one for a mountain bike? I would prefer the stiffest, as I do tricks but I don't really know which one is the stiffest. I seen both aluminum as well as carbon fiber handlebars for under 20bucks. Then, should I go for a curved or a flat handlebar? I ride in town, I am about 1.80m tall. I am a male at about 65 kgs also doing work outs. This is neither to skinny nor to fat. I believe its ideal. I do not make huge jumps, just some drops from less than half a meter. I also believe the handlebar should be large at about 70cm in length, so that I can have a lot of grip when doing my tricks. 
Ps.I wouldn't do any barspins, so I dont care about the length. I just do some hops, bunny hops, manuals, endos, etc. No backflips or frontflips or any stuff like that. Now what is your opinion on my case?
**Edit:** I really much like the design of the carbon fibre handebar whereas the aluminium handlebar is plain paint with a name on it. For the carbon fibre handebar it says that is has passed the EN 14766 Standards and the JAPAN JIS Standards. What to you think?

Comment: Carbon vs Aluminium is basically how much you want to spend.  Curved or flat is related to your riding position.   Both answers come from you, not us.

Comment: Carbon is lighter and offers far better small bump compliance.

Comment: Oversized steel.

Comment: Personal decision, based on money, comfort and style of riding. Aluminum won't break on you, I have seen carbon handlebars snap. Big air with hard landings, I would not want carbon.

Comment: Welcome to bicycles.SE!  Have a look at [the tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) for advice about how the site works---it's different than the usual forum-style site.  You probably were downvoted because your question is so brief.  Consider editing the question to tell us what kind of mountain biking you want to do, how much experience you've had, what your budget is, whether you're an aggressive or a gentle rider, what your general body type is (man/woman?  short/tall/hefty/skinny/young/old?), and so on.  Then we can give you more meaningful advice.

Comment: Oh thanks! Hadn't really seen the tour and I just did it now. I also improved my question as you told me. Thanks!

Comment: @ojs I am riding on some really heavy steel right now and see how stiff it is but it weighs way to much. This is why I want to put a carbon fibre or aluminum handlebar on.

Comment: An often cited reason to avoid carbon bars is that they're usually the first thing to hit the road in a crash. With alloy bars if they're not bent they're probably fine (but if they are, better to replace then than just bend them back), carbon can have defects under the surface that're harder to notice so it's often recommended that you replace them any time you've had a big crash. Cheapo carbon even more so.

Comment: Carbon bars for less than 20 $ sound VERY scary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with aluminium... But just a note of caution.... IF you do decide on carbon, steer clear of cheap versions. There are many many places selling cheapo carbon bars etc that are fake! 
The likes of FSA etc are now having to insert multiple hologram and ultra violet features into their bars, seatposts, stems etc as there are so many fakes being reported.
There was recently a BBC report on this growing problem...

http://www.cyclingweekly.co.uk/news/product-news/dangers-of-fake-bike-parts-highlighted-by-bbc-documentary-203011

Comment: Thank you a lot! Didn't really know there could be some fakes around. I will look it up again and then decide... How much could a carbon fibre handebar cost?

Comment: Thank you a lot! Didn't really know there could be some fakes around. I will look it up again and then decide... Would this be good enough? (Passed EN 14766 Standards and the JAPAN JIS Standards.) How much could a carbon fibre handebar cost?

Comment: For carbon MTB bars firstly make sure you buy from a reputable supplier... You're going to be looking at about £70+